# bind nested ng-repeat to model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In the following example, I should ask for the name of six students. They will be grouped according to bedroom type.

- 2 -> double
- 1 -> single
- 3 -> tiple

So, it means that I'll have a array of students (6 students). I would like to get their names. I was trying to create a variable like 'count' and put as ng-model of the input and increment during the loop, but it didn't work.

full html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller='SampleController'>
    <div ng-repeat='i in numberOfAccommodations track by $index'>
        Bedroom {{$index}}

        <span ng-repeat='x in numberOfStudents[$index]'>
            Student {{$index}}

            <input type='text' ng-model='abroadStudents[???].name' /> <!-- this input to student model -->
        </span>         
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='test' ">
    <script>
        angular.module('sampleApp',[]).controller('SampleController',function($scope){

            $scope.abroadStudents = new Array[6];

            $scope.abroadAccommodation = new Array();
            $scope.abroadAccommodation.push({ "bedroomType": 2}, { "bedroomType": 1 }, {"bedroomType": 3});

            $scope.numberOfAccommodations = function()
            {
                var arr = new Array();

                for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.abroadAccommodation.length ; i++)
                {
                    arr.push(i);
                }

                return arr;
            }();            

            $scope.numberOfStudents = function()
            {
                var arr = new Array();

                for (var x = 0 ; x < $scope.abroadAccommodation.length ; x++)
                {
                    var temp = 0;
                    var intArr = new Array();

                    do
                    {
                        intArr.push(temp);
                        temp++;
                    }
                    while(temp < $scope.abroadAccommodation[x].bedroomType);

                    arr.push(intArr);
                }

                return arr;
            }();            

        });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you missing some code here?  what does `foi()` do?

Comment: @Claies oooops, my bad. I was testing a console.log in the abroadAccommodation ... I've removed that.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve.  You asked about using `ng-model`, but as I try to recreate your code in a plunker, I'm not seeing any `ng-model`. I assume you meant it to be on the input, but what javascript variable are you expecting that input to be bound to?

Comment: @Claies I'm sorry, I've update the sample with "<input type='text' ng-model='abroadStudents[???].name' />" ...So, I would like to bind each input to a position of the abroadStudents array. The problem is that I don't have a index position that goes from 0 to 5. I've tried a $scope.count and incrementing that, but didn't work.

Comment: `$index` isn't really the right thing to use here anyway, I don't think.  `$index` doesn't refer to the item's position in it's respective array, it refers to the item's internal position in the `<ng-repeat>` iteration. If you intend these input boxes to refer to items in `abroadStudents`, you would need an `ng-repeat` that iterated through that array.

Comment: I think you are approaching this wrong anyway, trying to deal with array indexes.  Give me a few minutes to work up an alternative example that I think does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ok @Claies . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your logic to create a more logical structure of objects which does not require relying upon the `$index`.  It creates an Array of `room` objects, then iterates through the array of `abroadAccommodation`.  For each `abroadAccommodation`, it adds a room, and based on type, adds the appropriate number of `student` objects.  It is then very easy to use `ng-repeat` to iterate through each `room` to identify each `student`.

Note I also am using [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach#!) here.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='SampleController'>
  <div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
    {{room.roomNum}}
    <div ng-repeat="student in room.students">
      {{student.bed}}
      <input ng-model="student.name" />
    </div>
  </div>

  Student List:
  <div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
    <div ng-repeat="student in room.students">
      {{student.name}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module('sampleApp', []).controller('SampleController', function($scope) {

      $scope.abroadAccommodation = new Array();
      $scope.abroadAccommodation.push({
        "bedroomType ": 2
      }, {
        "bedroomType ": 1
      }, {
        "bedroomType ": 3
      });

      $scope.rooms = function() {
        var arr = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.abroadAccommodation, function(type, count) {

          var room = {
            "roomNum": "room " + (count + 1),
            students: []
          };
          angular.forEach(type, function(numBeds) {

            for (i = 0; i < numBeds; i++) {
              room.students.push({
                "bed": "bed " + (i + 1),
                "name": "student" + Math.random()
              });
            }
            arr.push(room);
          })

        });

        return arr;
      }();

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YaPo54NUBPk9AnZkGcCc?p=preview

Comment: we all start somewhere... I hope that you can see the structure I'm after here.  Generally, in angular, it is best to structure the data first, and allow the UI to naturally line up with the data, rather than try to plan the DOM.